# After reading the excel in the react , my excel(json) data is not geting updated in the usestate (setItems)

Tags: reactjs, excel, react-hooks, use-state

As I m new to this project, so can anybody help to get out of this.

I have successfully read the excel and converted it into the JSON and after that, it is successfully showing me in the console, but when I update it in the setItems to render the data in the table, it is not getting updated.

I m uploaded my code please check it.

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const readfiles = (file, e) => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filereader = new FileReader();
      filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      filereader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {
          type: "buffer",
        });
        const ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];

        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        resolve(data);
      };

      filereader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });

    p.then((d) => {
      console.log("data", d);
      setItems(d);
      console.log(items)
    });
    };
```

in console.log("data", d) it is showing data, but in console.log(items) it is showing nothing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvgB1.png)

Here is have my table jsx

```
  return (
    <div style={MainStyle}>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          readfiles(file);
        }}
      />

      <Container>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Territory name</th>
              <th>territory date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items?.map((d) => {
              <tr key={d.territory_name}>
                <td>{d.Hours}</td>
                <td>{d.territory_name}</td>
                <td>{d.timeoff_period}</td>
              </tr>;
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

data is not getting render in the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React hooks are **asynchronous**, meaning you might not be able to access the data *right after* you set it via `useState`.

If you really want to use it (not just `console.log()` it), you can take advantage of `useEffect`, passing state as the second parameter. More on `useEffect` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

EDIT: For your second problem, you either `return` :

```
<tbody>
{items?.map((d) => {
  return (<tr key={d.territory_name}>
    <td>{d.Hours}</td>
    <td>{d.territory_name}</td>
    <td>{d.timeoff_period}</td>
  </tr>);
})}
</tbody>
```

or you replace your `{}` by `()` :

```
<tbody>
{items?.map((d) => (
  <tr key={d.territory_name}>
    <td>{d.Hours}</td>
    <td>{d.territory_name}</td>
    <td>{d.timeoff_period}</td>
  </tr>;
))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: It really works, but still, data is not getting mapped in the table? I m putting items.map(), but still, data is not rendering in the table.

Comment: It might not be the problem, but you need to `return` something in your `map` function. You either need to `return (<tr>your code here</tr)` or you need to replace your curly braces `{` just before your function `=>` by parentheses `(`.

Comment: That is really great, it definitely works. Thank you :-)

Comment: Actually, if we don't put the useEffect , then also it will work. I haven't put the return on the table that's why it is not working before.

Comment: Yes in your case it will, but I didn't have your second file initially so I didn't know what you wanted to achieve exactly. :)